# What is wrong with my .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do an htaccess file to work with my RestApi, my htaccess is located in

```
http://www.example.com/appregalos/ApiRest`
```

My problem is that if I write

```
http://www.example.com/appregalos/ApiRest/users`
```

It doesn't do anything, but the action that I want do is redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/appregalos/ApiRest/api2.php?rquest=users
```

What is happening?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z]+)/?$ api2.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule "^users/([0-9]+)/?$" api2.php?rquest=users&id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule "^users/([A-Za-z0-9_.@]+)/?$" api2.php?rquest=users&email=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your .htaccess is located in

```
http://www.example.com/appregalos/ApiRest
```

You should use a `RewriteBase` for that directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /appregalos/ApiRest/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z]+)/?$ api2.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule "^users/([0-9]+)/?$" api2.php?rquest=users&id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule "^users/([A-Za-z0-9_.@]+)/?$" api2.php?rquest=users&email=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```